# How do I make TortoiseSVN ignore empty directories that have been removed from the repo?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I've got some directories that have been moved or renamed. The Linux command line SVN client ignores these directories. The TortoiseSVN plugin for Explorer shows them. If I delete them and update, they come back.

All of the file movement and deletion has been done using the Linux SVN CLI tools. When doing an 'svn update' or even a fresh 'svn co' on a Linux system, these empty directories are not shown.

When doing a fresh checkout using TortoiseSVN, the empty directories are created, even though they don't exist in the HEAD revision anymore.

How can I make them go away?

Comment: Please provide additional information.  Did you do the move using "mv", or "svn mv"?  Did you move them with the intent of hiding them from SVN, or for some other reason?  If you delete the directories and update using the CLI client, do the directories come back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting the directories in the Windows working copy and now the directories are gone. No idea why that was necessary.

Closing question...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a client problem. Unless I'm misreading you, your SVN manipulations were correctly done.

Several options:

- your client is set to get the wrong revision
- you client is somehow running into a cache of some sort (are you running SVN over port 80?)
- someone has something fancy set up on the server like 2 repos mirroring each other but badly.

Only the first one seems likely to me. What I'd do is figure out what URL the linux side is using and do a fresh checkout on the Windows side with that to a new location and specifically check to make sure the revision is set to head. If that doesn't work, I don't known what the issue could be. If it does, it limits the problems a lot.

p.s., just had a thought, failing the above try a revert to the head revision. I don't think it will work but...